# class level error : <identifier> expected in java

Tags: java

when I am coding this at class level

```
int a;
a=5;
```

it throws error : "identifier expected"

But when I declare it as a local variable like

```
void m1() {
    int a;
    a=5;
}
```

No error is thrown.

Comment: Because scopes are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing this at class level, you're allowed to combine declaration and assignment in just **one** statement, like:

```
class A {
    int a = 5;
}
```

Otherwise, you have to wrap the assignment withing a block (constructor, method, initializer block). For example:

```
class A {
    int a;

    public A() { a = 5; } //via constructor

    void setA() { a = 5; } //via method

    { a = 5; } //via initializer block
}
```

Comment: any specific reason for this rule ?

Comment: That's how the language is designed.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a value to variable is called as expression.  We could not write any expression in a class.  We could do the same in method bodies.  Basically we could right expressions when scope is defined and hence allowed in method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason following:

```
int a=5;
```

declared at class level does not produce compile time error when:

```
void m1() {
    int a;
    a=5;
}
```

is declared because `m1()` has its own scope.

For **instance**, if don't declare and access variable `a`, it would refer to class's field, where as when you declare `a` locally, you'd always refer to one declared inside `a`.

**PS :** You cannot do following at class level:

```
int a;
a=5;
```

You'd have to:

```
int a=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not write code into the class, only in method, constructor or into initializer {} block. That is why you get syntax error.
Probably you want to use initializer block like this:

```
class my{
 int a;
 {
  a=1;
 }
}
```